# Divergence with respect to pull-back metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, submanifold, divergence-operator

Let $(M,G)$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$ and $S$ be a submanifold of $M$ of dimension $m$. Consider a vector field $X$ on $S$. $X$ is also a vector fieldd on $M$, so we can compute its [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Relation_to_the_exterior_derivative) in some coordinates chart $x$ for $M$ as $$\text{div}X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{D}}\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}_i} \left( \sqrt{D} X^i \right)$$
with $D = |\det{G}|$.

Let now $g$ be the metric on $S$ induced by the one on $M$ (that is, $g$ is the pull-back of $G$ along the inclusion).

$X$ is a vector field on $S$, so we can compute its divergence in some coordinates chart $y$ for $S$ as
$$\text{div}X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}_i} \left( \sqrt{d} X^i \right)$$
with $d = |\det{g}|$.

**Is there any relation between the two expressions? In particular, if $X$ is divergence-free as a vector field in the ambient manifold, is it also divergence-free as a vector field on the submanifold?**

The answer seems to be "**yes**" from an example, but I'd like to get a more theoretical understanding.

**Example** Let $M$ be the three-dimensional Euclidean space and $S$ the standard sphere. The vector field $$(y+z) \partial_x + (-x+z)\partial_y + (-x-y)\partial_z$$
is parallel to the sphere and divergence-free with respect to the Euclidean metric, and after a calculation it's divergence with respect to the pull-back metric is $$\sqrt{2} \left( \frac{1}{\tan{(\theta)}} - \frac{1}{\tan{\left(\theta \right)}}\right) \sin{\left(\phi + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)} = 0
$$

Comment: See [Proposition 2 on page 2](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/var_volume.pdf).

Comment: @IvoTerek thanks, your notes are very insightful - but they don't quite answer my question. To rephrase it with your notation, let $\iota: \Sigma \hookrightarrow M$ be an embedded submanifold of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. I understand that $\text{div}_{\iota^*g}: \Gamma(T\Sigma) \to C^{\infty}(\Sigma)$ extends to $\text{div}_{\Sigma}: \Gamma(TM|_{\Sigma}) \to C^{\infty}(\Sigma)$ as described in Proposition 2, but my question is: given $X \in \Gamma(T\Sigma)$, is there a relation between $\text{div}_g(X) \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $\text{div}_{\iota^*{g}}(X) \in C^{\infty}(\Sigma)$?

Comment: I believe that $\text{div}_{\iota^*g}X = \iota^* \text{div}_{g}X$; @IvoTerek is this true, and if so would you have any reference / sketch proof suggetion?

Comment: The divergence of a vector field on $M$ requires that vector field be defined on an open subset of $M$. If you have a vector field $X$ defined only on $S$ only, then the divergence of $X$ on $M$ is undefined, because the divergence contains a derivative of $X$ in a direction not tangent to $S$. If you extend $X$ to a neighborhood of $S$, the divergence of the extended vector field will depend on the extension itself. You can say, however that there *exists* an extension so that the divergence of the extended vector field equals the divergence of $X$ on $S$.

Comment: Thanks @Deane, it makes sense. Let's then start from a vector field on $M$ that is parallel to $S$, i.e. $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ and $X_p \in T_{p}S \subset T_{p}M$ for all $p \in S$. Is there then a well-defined notion of $\text{div}_{\iota^{*}g}X$, and does it relate to $\iota^{*}\text{div}_{g}X?$

Comment: We’re already assuming $X$ is tangent to $S$, right? I think the way to extend it to a neighborhood of $S$ is to parallel translate it along geodesics normal to $S$.